# Why is reader in java reading characters wrong?

Tags: java, character-encoding, reader

So i have been trying to read different characters from an unknown file (my own file extension .xs) but it doesn't seem to work. For example it reads this character '¸' as 65533 and its ASCII code is 184. Is it a problem with my code or with encoding (i am programming in Intellij).
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Reader reading = new FileReader("ala.xs");

        int character;
        while ((character = reading.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) character;
            System.out.println((int)ch);
        }

        reading.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the file ala.xs:"š           ° otmkla¸HR8"

Here is the output of my program:"65533
32
65533
32
111
116
109
107
108
97
65533
72
82
56"

I tried changing encoding but it doesn't seem to work and i am honestly losing hope. Is this error becouse of reader reading wrong or me?

Comment: *Here is the file ala.xs:"š ° otmkla¸HR8"* How did you produce it and write it? 65533 is a replacement character and appears several times in your output, indicating that there are problems with encoding. You should probably use an explicit encoding when you read it, so use an `InputStreamReader` with UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here is the file ala.xs:"š ° otmkla¸HR8"

How did you produce it and write it? 65533 is a replacement character and appears several times in your output, indicating that there are problems with encoding. You should probably use an explicit encoding when you read it, as currently you *assume* an encoding, so use an InputStreamReader with UTF-8

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Reader reading = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("ala.xs"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        int character;
        while ((character = reading.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) character;
            System.out.println((int) ch);
        }

        reading.close();
    }
}
```

Showing correct file and execution:

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ cat ala.xs;echo 
š ° otmkla¸HR8
goose@t410:/tmp$ java Main
353
32
176
32
111
116
109
107
108
97
184
72
82
56
goose@t410:/tmp$
```

Obviously, make sure you can save it correctly in the first place as UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tool you can use for diagnostics

```
testStr1 = "ï»¿Report Type, Icon URL";
encoded1 = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(testStr1);
restored = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(encoded1);
System.out.println(testStr1 + "\n" + encoded1 + "\n" + restored);
```

And the output I got from that code:

```
š ° otmkla¸HR8
\u0161\u0020\u00b0\u0020\u006f\u0074\u006d\u006b\u006c\u0061\u00b8\u0048\u0052\u0038
š ° otmkla¸HR8
```

Note that the forth symbol from the end has a code 00b8 which is Hexadecimal for 184. So, your data is intact. the answer from @g00se is correct - you need to use explicit encoding. If you like to use this utility it comes with Open source MgntUtils library (written and maintained by me). Here is the [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html). The library could be obtained as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)